# Use Gist to get Financial Reports From Google Finance

Tags: python, git, cmd, gist

I would like to download financial reports from Google Finance and i have discovered this [gist](https://gist.github.com/knoguchi/6952087) and [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740116/programmatic-access-to-detailed-historical-financial-data). However i am used to downloading a git repository go to the file `directory` where the downloaded git is and with the use of the `cmd` excecute the `setup.py` to setup and then use the git in my machine.

However once I download the gist i get

- `pax_global_header`
- A `folder` named `gist6952087-f454536fdd54c47d42017aa1e9f286524b9bd9e8` which inside has a `gistfile1.txt`

How can i actually put this thing to work with my python from the `cmd`?

**EDIT**

```
I have tried to do this:

C:\Users\Μαρίνος\Desktop\New folder\gist>python gistfile1.py -h
  File "gistfile1.py", line 72
    except Exception, _:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gistfile1.txt` is the script; the gist author just didn't give it a name.

If you want, give it a name with a `.py` extension instead, and run the script with Python:

```
python gistfile1.py -h
```

gives you the command-line help message.

Do make sure you have [pyquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) installed first.

The file is written for Python 2. If you have Python 3 installed, it is easy enough to have it converted:

```
python3 -m lib2to3 -w gistfile1.py
```

This will replace the script with one that will work just fine on Python 3.

Comment: Just a sec let me test

Comment: Do i need to `python gistfile1.py install` or not? I will try to use it at once

Comment: @Codo: no, this is not a package. It's just *one script*.

Comment: I did what you have said me but gives me an error `C:\Users\Μαρίνος\Desktop\New folder\gist>python gistfile1.py -h
  File "gistfile1.py", line 72
    except Exception, _:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Codo: it's a *Python 2* script. You are running it with Python 3.

Comment: Oh dear! Is there a way to have Python2 and 3 on your machine? I am running an application that works only with Python 3...

Comment: @Codo: you can, they can be installed side by side.

Comment: Thank you so much! One final question how will my machine actually know how which `python` edition to use when i type say: `python setup.py`? ___when i type this i am going to the downloaded gist directory not in the directory where a Python edition is downloaded

Comment: @Codo: I tested using the Python 2-to-3 conversion tool, and it works fine for this script. Instructions added.

Comment: For Windows, read the [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) documentation, it'll tell you everything you need to know about running multiple versions of Python on a Windows machine, including picking what Python interpreter is used for what script.

Comment: @Codo: not if you have converted the script with `lib2to3`, you don't.

Comment: The new converted file has the suffix `bak` which i will remove. :P thank you so much again

Comment: @Codo: no, `.bak` is the *back-up*, the unaltered original file; the file itself was re-written.

Comment: Ohhhhhh oh dear thanks i am a catastrophe on keyboard